# how to choose which battery to discharge from in linux / manjaro?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, power-management, battery

so im facing an issue with my t440s , it has 2 batteries and it discharges from the second battery till 0 percent and that damages my battery .

im on linux/manjaro nad i want to switch to the second battery after the second one hits `10 percent`.
is there a way to configure this?